# Azure Logic App creation of Redis Cache requires x-ms-api-version

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps, azure-redis-cache

I'm building an Azure Logic App and try to automate the creation of an Azure Redis Cache. There is a specific action for this (Create or update resource) which I was able to bring up:

[image: Defintion in Logic App]

As you can see I entered `2016-02-01` as the api version. I was trying different values here just guessing from other api versions I know from Microsoft. I can't find any resource on this on the internet. The result of this step will be:

```
{
    "error": 
    {
        "code": "InvalidResourceType",
        "message": "The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.Cache' for api version '2016-02-01'."
    }
}
```

What is the correct value for `x-ms-api-version` and where can I find the history for this value based on the resource provider?

Comment: Can you try with `2016-04-01` API version?

Comment: @GauravMantri Same error.

Comment: That's weird. I have taken the version from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/redis/redis/create.

Comment: @GauravMantri Good resource for getting the version thanks! Maybe the "preview" statement in the title of the task means "not working currently" ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Resource Provider: Microsoft.Cache
Name: Redis/<yourrediscachename>
x-ms-api-version: 2017-02-01
```

One easy way to know the supported versions for each resource type is using CLI on your Azure Portal, e.g.

```
az provider show --namespace Microsoft.Cache --query "resourceTypes[?resourceType=='Redis'].apiVersions | [0]"
```

would return:

```
[
  "2017-02-01",
  "2016-04-01",
  "2015-08-01",
  "2015-03-01",
  "2014-04-01-preview",
  "2014-04-01"
]
```

I made it work with:

[image]

HTH

Comment: I still get the error "The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.Cache' for api version '2014-04-01'." But +1 for hinting me to `az provider show`.

Comment: Check the updated answer with the image. It worked for me :) @sprinter252